# Hide folder from displaying in browser URL and handle redirects

Tags: apache, drupal

I have a website set up right now like this:

http://www.mysite.com/cms/index.php

I'd like to have the /cms folder hidden from the URL.  I also need to manage redirects from the old folder structure - if that is necessary.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^/cms(.*) $1 [redirect=301,last]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /cms/$1
```